# ModalPopupExtender Button Problem

Tags: asp.net, popup, modalpopupextender

I am trying to figure out why my ModalPopupExtender keeps closing, everytime a user clicks either button its running the code behind because I put a break point in and it is breaking there, but the modalPopup immediately closes, which isnt good because if it has any errors in the process they cant be displayed. So how do I stop the modalpopup from closing itself? I didnt specify a OKControlID or a CancelControlID.

Panel Code:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panele" runat="server" style="display: none; position:absolute; top: 50%; left: 35%; width: 500px; height: 350px; background-color: White; border: solid 1px black; padding-left: 15px; text-align: left;">
        <asp:ImageButton ID="CloseEBtn" runat="server" 
        ImageUrl="images/CloseButton.png" style="float: right; margin-right: 3px; margin-top: 3px;" 
        onclick="CloseEBtn_Click" />
<strong>Name:<asp:TextBox ID="fromTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></strong>
    <asp:Button ID="SndBtn" runat="server" Text="Send" onclick="SndBtn_Click" />
&nbsp;<asp:Button ID="ClrBtn" runat="server" Text="Clear" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="msglabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</asp:Panel>
```

My ModalPopupExtender Code:

```
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="popup" runat="server" 
    TargetControlID="SIBtn" PopupControlID="Panele" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>
```

CodeBehind:

```
    protected void SndBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        msglabel.Text = "The Window Didnt Close";
    }
    protected void ClrBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fromTextBox.Text = "";
        toTextBox.Text = "";
        subjectTextBox.Text = "";
        MessageTextBox.Text = "";
        msglabel.Text = "";
    }
```

Comment: Please post your codebehind methods as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By code-behind running if you mean the page posts back, modal popups do not explicitly reload themselves.  You have to write some code from the server to show the Modal Popup; there is a Server-side Show() method on the extender and a client-side show() method like:

```
$find("<%= mpe.ClientID %>").show();
```

HTH.

Comment: the problem is I have other things that generate a postback on the page so How would I determine if that postback was caused by the modalpopup?

Comment: You might want to inject the script suggested by Brian from code-behind upon button click something like here: http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/JavaScript_with_ASP_NET_2_0_Pages_Part1.aspx#s6

Comment: Do you know which controls trigger the postback?  It's going to have to be detecting the control postback and knowing that control is inside the modal popup.  Or, don't know why I didn't think of it, even better, use an updatepanel.  An updatepanel control should prevent this issue...

Answer (score 1):

For me, `UseSubmitBehavior="false"` on the `asp:Button` did the trick.